# Send HTTP Packets without browser?

Tags: http, telnet

I guess I have two questions:

1. I am trying  to send an HTTP request to web server without using a web-browser. I have read that the most common way to do this with Telnet, but I was wondering of other ways.
2. Also, I think my telnet has a problem. I activated telnet client, and go on the command window and type in telnet, then type "open IP-address 80" and it says "connecting to IP-address ..." forever, but never lets me go past that. Has any of you encountered this problem? 
   Also, I noticed on Wireshark that the TCP handshake happens properly.

Please and Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should also check out the curl command-line utility: http://curl.haxx.se/ Basically, it's a cool little piece of software that makes HTTP requests (and supports other protocols as well). Also check out hurl: http://www.hurl.it/ which is kind of a Web application version of curl.

Comment: curl is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a port? Port 80 is usually used for HTTP requests.

`telnet www.some-site.com/some-page.html 80`

Once you have connected you need to make a `GET` request. (Send a command of `GET`).

Comment: Yes, I did Specify port 80. When I don't, it uses the default port 23 and the connection fails.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish the same thing using `sockets` or a `WebClient` (C#):

The default way is `Telnet`:

From the telnet command prompt you could do:

```
 o   host   port>         (o www.website.com 80)
 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
```

Using a `WebClient` (Note: This is a C# WebClient object):

```
 var webClient = new WebClient();
 webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Agent");
 Stream responseStream = webClient.OpenRead("http://www.google.com")
```

The response from the server would be stored inside the `responseStream` object.